# Gram Schmidt orthogonalization

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

I would need a small proof of this theorem because I got stuck in the inductive step because I tried to do induction after $n\geq 1$

(Gram Schmidt orthogonalization)
The system of polynomials $\{ \varphi_0, \varphi_1, \varphi_2,\ldots,\varphi_n \}\subset P_n$ given by the following relations:

$
\varphi_0(x) = 1
$

$
\varphi_1(x) = (x-a_1)\varphi_0(x) = x-a_1
$

$
\varphi_k(x) = (x-a_k)\varphi_{k-1}(x)-b_k\varphi_{k-2}(x)\,,\quad k\geq 2
$

where,

$
a_k = \dfrac{\langle x\varphi_{k-1}, \varphi_{k-1} \rangle_{w}}{\langle \varphi_{k-1}, \varphi_{k-1} \rangle_w}\,,\quad k\geq 1
$

$
b_k = \dfrac{\langle x\varphi_{k-1}, \varphi_{k-2} \rangle_{w}}{\langle \varphi_{k-2}, \varphi_{k-2} \rangle_w}\,,\quad k\geq 2
$

it is orthogonal (w is a weight function that for simplicity can be considered as equal to 1).

$\langle f,g \rangle_w = \int_a^b w(x)f(x)g(x)\,dx$

Thanks a lot!